# c++ aggregate initializer g++ bug?

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization

I have a problem compiling this simple aggregate named initialization with g++

```
struct A  {
    int a;
};
struct B {
    int b;
};
struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};

void fun() {
    A a{0};
    B b {12} ;
    // g++ is OK with this
    C c{  .a=a , .b=b };
    // g++ is OK with this
    C cc{ 0, {12}};
    // msvc, clang accept this but g++ does not
    C ccc{.a=0, .b={12}};
}
```

g++ complains with `error: 'A' has no non-static data member named 'b`

Is this a gcc bug ?

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, it's an everyone-else bug (I filed [llvm bug #49020](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49020), which Richard Smith has already fixed on trunk). gcc is correct in rejecting (although the error makes no sense. `A` indeed does have no non-static data member named `b` but that isn't the issue...)

This:

```cpp
C ccc{.a=0, .b={12}};
```

*should* be ill-formed. What this means is you're initializing the `a` member of `C` with `=0` and the `b` member of `C` with `={12}`.

But you can't initialize an `A` from `= 0`. This is ill-formed:

```cpp
A a = 0;
```

Hence, the broader initialization is also ill-formed. I don't know why everyone else accepts.

Comment: If that's true, why does this work: `C cc{ 0, {12}};`?

Comment: @NicolBolas Brace elision, but that only applies if we have an *initializer-list* (as opposed to a *designated-initializer-list*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, given the third line appears as a mere substitution of values on the second line in the first, 
```C c{  .a=a , .b=b };
    C cc{ 0, {12}};
    C ccc{.a=0, .b={12}};``` 
it did not seems logical.
I missed the brace elision thing... ```C ccc{.a={0}, .b={12}};``` works.